# Get Distinct List from csv file based on first column

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have the following list of stings taken from a csv file...

```
List<string> listOfRecords;
```

Each line is a string in the list...

```
one,bob,black
two,steve,smith
three,bill,brown
one,jill,brown
one,sue,smith
```

I would like to remove duplicates based on the first value on each line. Resulting in...

```
one,bob,black
two,steve,smith
three,bill,brown
```

I thought the code would look something like....

```
distinctlist = Select listOfRecords.split(',')[0].distinct
```

this is obviously wrong but I wanted to avoid making a list of lists and doing it that way. Thinking linq would be simpler.

All the posts I can find on here seem quite complex or do not address the specifics of my question. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: So you want the first of each "duplicate", where you base your "duplicate" rule on the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with a `GroupBy`:

```
var distinctByFirstColumn = listOfRecords
  .GroupBy(x => x.Split(',')[0])
  .Select(x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use `HashSet<String>` and simple `foreach` loop instead of *Linq* (which, IMHO, is overshoot) here:

```
var distinctList = new List<String>();

HashSet<String> taken = new HashSet<String>();

foreach (var line in listOfRecords) 
  // you don't want to split all the line, but 1st item only
  if (taken.Add(line.SubString(0, line.IndexOf(','))) 
    distinctList.Add(line);
```

**Edit**: In case of a *real csv file*:

```
  private static IEnumerable<String> CsvDistinctLines(String fileName) {
    HashSet<String> taken = new HashSet<String>();

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName)) 
      if (taken.Add(line.SubString(0, line.IndexOf(','))) 
        yield return line;
  }

  ...

  var distinctList = CsvDistinctLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv").ToList();
```

Comment: I would move the implementation to a separate method though. Having the `HashSet<string>` in the same scope as other logic is somewhat cluttered.

Comment: @Kvam: when implementing as a separate method (see my edit), just put the `HashSet<String>` into this method.