# Read distinct values from CSV to Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, linq, csv, csvhelper

I have a CSV file where column A will have repeated values as per [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQCGP.png). From this CSV file, I only want my `datagridview` to display distinct values from Column A as well as skip the header column titled **Name** as per Image 1. So my `datagridview` should display as per [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUM0u.png).

However, with my code below, the datagridview displayed as per [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qfQb.png). Below is my code. I'm using `Linq` and `Csvhelper`. I have used [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563453/get-distinct-list-from-csv-file-based-on-first-column) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374627/csvhelper-how-to-filter-a-column-and-return-only-distinct-values) as reference. Hope to get some help

**Class 1**

```
    public string Name
    {
      get; set;
    }
```

**Form 3**

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //Create Datatable
    DataSet dts = new DataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));

    //Read the data from the CSV file
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"\Users\d_sim\Desktop\test.csv");
    CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(streamReader);
    reader.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    reader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

    //Make Class 1 into a list.
    List<Class1> records = reader.GetRecords<Class2>().ToList();

    //Only Read the applicable property and display in datagridview. IRL Class1 has many properties but I only include one in this question
    var distinctbyproperty = records.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First());
    dataTable.Rows.Add(distinctbyproperty.ToString());
    dts.Tables.Add(dataTable);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of class1 by the way? You don't use that in the code?

Comment: @masyita shariff does use `Class1` for the `List<Class1> records =` line. There is a slight bug there, the rest of it should be `reader.GetRecords<Class1>().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filtering your records

```
records.GroubBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First()).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi @StuiterSlurf thanks for your suggestion. Ive used your solution and my datagridview output is still the same, no changes.

Comment: on what property does it needs to be distinct? The distinct works on the entire element.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering you have works fine. You just need to add each row to your dataTable individually.

```cs
foreach (var item in distinctbyproperty)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Name);
}
```